# Firestore update snapshotListener replies are out of order even when waiting for .get()

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Running a hello-world of writing a few sequential true/false values to a firestore db, with the goal of keeping a local variable in sync with the cloud.

The callback events seem to be out of order, even when each `update()` call waits before kicking off the next one by using `get()`

I write 'false', 'true', 'true'
But the RESPONSEs are 'true', 'false', 'true'

Even stranger, sometimes there are 3 responses, even when I only made 2 requests.  Is it possible things are getting queued up for the next time I launch the app?  If so, is there any way to be sure to flush before shutdown?

My concern is that my local app might be left with an incorrect impression of what the most recent value is.

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials
import com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val firestoreOptions = FirestoreOptions.newBuilder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
                    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("serviceAccountKey.json")))
            .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
            .build()
    val db = firestoreOptions.service!!

    val docRef = db.collection("users").document("tmpUser").collection("devices").document("tmpDevice")
    docRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ ->
        (snapshot?.data ?: mapOf()).forEach { key, value ->
            println("  RESPONSE: '$key'='$value'")
        }
    }
    println("Listening...")

    val writeResultFuture2 = docRef.update(mapOf("running" to false))
    println("REQUEST 'false' at ${writeResultFuture2.get().updateTime}")

    val writeResultFuture3 = docRef.update(mapOf("running" to true))
    println("REQUEST 'true' at ${writeResultFuture3.get().updateTime}")

    val writeResultFuture4 = docRef.update(mapOf("running" to true))
    println("REQUEST 'true' at ${writeResultFuture4.get().updateTime}")

    delay(5_000)
    println("Stopping.")
}
```

Output:

```
Listening...
  RESPONSE: 'running'='true'
  RESPONSE: 'running'='false'
REQUEST 'false' at 2018-10-12T21:07:25.530943000Z
REQUEST 'true' at 2018-10-12T21:07:25.686950000Z
  RESPONSE: 'running'='true'
REQUEST 'true' at 2018-10-12T21:07:25.686950000Z
Stopping.
```

Comment: Can you print out the log of your most recent run with this code?

Comment: @ToddKerpelman edited to include output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the short answer is this seems to be working as designed.

First, keep in mind that when you create an `updateListener`, it will fire not just on updates, but also the very first time with whatever data already exists in the database. (And this is generally what you want -- it makes your code a lot easier to write because you just create your handler as your "All the data from the database" handler, whether it's from an initial retrieve or an update.) So that's why you get that first "true" response.

The second "false" response is from the first update that you apply.

The third "true" response is from the second update that you apply

The fourth "true" response never gets fired because the client SDK is generally smart enough to not call the handler again if the data from the database is exactly the same as the data that already exists. I'm guessing if that third update call were changed to something like, "Maybe", then you'd see that fourth response.